# Newbie in jQuery - focusIn and out on textareas

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck with my code. I use the focusin() function to detect the user interaction on a textarea. My concept:

- first init => all are collapsed with auto-height (50px)
- first focus-in => the focused element will be expanded to more pixels (150px)
- and now, I know, every time I get a new focusin on any of my elements, I had one, that are currently opend. Therefore I created a primitive routine for that idea:

---

```
var active = false;
myTextAreas.focusin(function() { 
    if (active == true) {
        myTextAreas.animate({"height" : 50}, 300);
        $(this).animate({"height" : 150}, 500); 
    } else {
        $(this).animate({"height" : 150}, 500);
        active = true;
    };
```

myTextAreas => Object with my HTML-elements (textareas). First time => do the else, second time => always the if-statement, which resizes all elements every time back AND than move my element up to more height. It works principally, BUT the first time when I do my little script, my box is resizing first and against the end the other box, which are the new focused-in-one, are starting too early with the new animate() function. Then it works... hmmm. But I think my code is not so pretty?

One feature I miss in my concept. When I focusout of any textarea, I want to animate all elements back, similar to the effect in my if-statement. But how can I say, do that, but only on the rest of my elements and not on my focus-in-textareas?

Maybe my concept is bad? I'm opened for a new one ... by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the active variable/need to track 'active' state by using the jquery blur event binding - also you do not need to invoke animate on all the input fields

```
myTextAreas.on('focus',function() { 
  $(this).animate({ height : 150 }, 500);  
});

myTextAreas.on('blur',function() { 
$(this).animate({ height : 50 }, 300);
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/axatin/3/edit#javascript,html,live